# what is the order of execution if I put a statement after the statement that do the recursion inside the function

Tags: c++, function, recursion

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print(int x)
{
    if(x==0)
        return ;
    else
    {
        print (x-1);    // statement 1
        cout<<x<< endl;  // statement 2 the issue ***********
    }
}
int main()
{
    int x;
    cout<<"please enter the number"<< endl;
    cin>>x;
    print(x);
    return 0;
}
```

can some one explain what happen with the statement that have a comment " statement the issue *****"
when I run the program it display 
1
2
3
4
5
but what I think it must display 
5
4
3
2
1
so the program execute the statement 1 before statement 2 or what happens 
and if the program execute the statement 1 first how it reaches the statement 2 and print what I get I think it must get out by the if statement

thanks

Comment: You have to understand concept of recursion first, please google it

Comment: @Filip, subtle.

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions. If you replaced `print(x-1)` with  `printf("%d\n", x-1)`, would you expect `5 4` or `4 5`?

Comment: Note that on the call, the process puts the data for the call on the stack BEFORE the cout<< statement.  That case holds until the end of the recursion and the stack is cleared and the cout<< statements are allowed to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay it's really simple.

Just consider these two points before moving on:

point 1:
When a function calls another function, the first function that calls the other is known as the "caller" function, the function getting called is known as the "callee".

point 2: when a callee is called, code execution stops at the point where the call was made and moves inside the callee and runs all the way through the callee, until it either finishes all the lines or reaches a return statement for a non void function or reaches another function call.

so here in your program: 
main () calls  print (x).
main() stops executing where print(x); was written

assuming x = 5,        5 is passed to void print (int x).

so now inside void. x is 5.

the if (5==0) statement is checked and evaluates to false, so else{} gets executed.

here is the part that confuses you:

inside else{}, there is a function call print (x-1);
this will call the function print (int x) recursively. passing it the value of 5-1=4.
so at this point, the function doesn't continue to the next line to execute cout << x << endl; instead it pauses inside this function and moves into another function.

notice how print (x-1) is called before cout<< x << endl; is even reached.

so print (x-1) runs, checking the if statement, and calling another print (x-1).
this continues, until x==0, which has a return with no return values which only terminates the function.

so the last function call (x==0) is terminated by the return; statement.

the function before it, which had the value of 1 (remember now x=1), continues from where it paused which was where print (x-1) was stated, and executes the code to the end of the function, so it executes cout<< x << endl; with x = 1.

then when this function is done, the function before it continues its execution in the same way , so first 1 was printed, now 2 gets printed, then 3, 4 and 5... until the whole cycle of functions waiting in line for their callee to finish executing ends..

recursive functions always get to the last call, and start evaluating and finalizing from the last one to the first one because a function call stops the caller from continuing to execute its code and instead makes the program execute inside the callee.

Answer (score 4):

Quite simply, follow the path of execution:

1. `print(5)` calls `print(4)`
2. `print(4)` calls `print(3)`
3. `print(3)` calls `print(2)`
4. `print(2)` calls `print(1)`
5. `print(1)` calls `print(0)`
6. `print(0)` returns
7. back in `print(1)`, it outputs `1` and returns
8. back in `print(2)`, it outputs `2` and returns
9. back in `print(3)`, it outputs `3` and returns
10. back in `print(4)`, it outputs `4` and returns
11. back in `print(5)`, it outputs `5` and returns
12. and then you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Pretend for a moment that instead of that recursive call to `print` the function has a call to some other function, let's call it `func()`. Clearly the call to `func()` will run before the stream insertions in statement 2.

The fact that there is a recursive call doesn't change that: the call to `print()` is made **before** the stream insertions in statement 2. So whatever that recursive calls does occurs **before** the stream insertions in statement 2.

So, for the top level call, when `x` is 5, the recursion all happens **first**, and then the function writes 5 to `std::cout`. So the 5 will be last.

Comment: okay got the point of what execute first but how and why it stream 1 then 2 so on tell five why begin from the 1 and why it executed for 5 times why not just execute the statement for just once after it finish the recursion

Answer (score 0):

It will go one layer deeper and as soon as x=0 it will roll up again from the bottom.

So it will output all the numbers from one to the first x.

Comment: so U mean it stream the values in the stack of recursion  but not look at the zero cuz it did not make any recursion . am I right ?

Comment: Yeah that's it @AhmedAraby